# Hosting own Git service?

Tags: git

I was wondering if it would be possible to install a git service for use by a small team. Would it be possible to install on a private network/locally or would it be more practical to install over a web network (e.g. a website domain).

Thanks and please point my in the right direction,
~Daniel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really simple to setup a git repo. Just do `git init --bare` on your server in a place that is accessible via ssh then your repo is `ssh://your_host/path_to_repo`.

Comment: @Zsub, yes, though it's much more difficult to create a public repository.

Comment: will it be password protected?

Comment: @Saad, it uses the same settings as ssh, so by default it is password protected, but if you put your public key onto the remote machine, it can authorise you without a password. (see, http://blogs.translucentcode.org/mick/archives/000230.html )

Answer (score 3):

In addition to dan_waterworths answer, I would like to suggest buying a subscription at, for example, GitHub. They probably have all the services you need, plus you don't need to worry about maintenance, backups, etc. and for a company with several developers, the cost of between $25 and $100 per month is quite reasonable.

Comment: note that it may be company policy that source must stay "in house".

Comment: Might be, but is not specified :) I got the impression it had to be easy, so I suggested an external website.

Comment: For in house you can get the GitHub Firewall Install. Which is your own private installation of GitHub in your own network.

Comment: If you need to go past github's $12/month plan, do yourself a favor and just purchase a low end VPS.  You will end up getting more disk space for private repositories and won't have any limitation of number of private repositories repositories or users It will also cost you less in most cases (you can easily find reliable low end VPS for under 22 a month).

Answer (score 2):

I found the "gitosis" package (installs easily on Ubuntu) to be very nice for a ssh-protected git repository if you need finer grained access control than "all with an ssh account can do everything".

Has worked well for us.

Answer (score 0):

For a small team, a simple network share can be enough.

But if you need authentication and fine-grained ACL on your repos, I would recommend **[gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/)**.

Comment: Will the network share work fine even with concurrent updates, or do you need to have it on a local disk?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: yes, the local protocol (http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html) supports concurrent updates.